# Image mask not following movie animation

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm putting a mask on an image that is being animated around the stage which works fine, but when i change the mask using as3 the mask stops following the image and stays in one place.. while the image moves around the stage... is there a way to force the mask to stick on the image?

```
// set the current mask to null
face_mc.face_one.mask = null;
// assign the new mask
face_mc.face_one.mask = customShape;

// the movie clip is animated by this method whcih tracks a point in a video clip
function cuepointlistener(evt:MetadataEvent):void{
    paramObj = evt.info.parameters;
    var values:Array = paramObj["Track Point 1_Attach Point"].split(/,/);
    face_mc.x = values[0];
    face_mc.y = values[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put both in a `Sprite` and move that instead?

Comment: They're both in a movie clip, isn't that the same thing?

Comment: It is, same thing. So you move the `MovieClip` around and the mask "falls out" of it and stays in one place after you change it? Can you post some code?

Comment: Is `customShape` inside `face_mc`?

Comment: do you maybe know of a way to change the shape of a mask instead of replacing it?

Comment: You can try to wrap it into a `Sprite`, only change the `Shape` inside and see what happens :)

Comment: post the code where you are creating and adding the mask to the display list

Comment: As for the difference between sprite and MovieClip they are the same but MovieClip has frame support.

Answer (score 0):

```
// customShape has to be a child of face_mc

face_mc.addChild( customShape  );
face_mc.face_one.mask = customShape;
```